# Toggle Mute in Unity 4.6

Tags: unity-game-engine, toggle

I'm making my own game in Unity 4.6. I have background music playing all the time. But i want to give my players the possibility to mute the music with a simple toggle.
I'm using C#. Anyone any ideas on how to do this?

Would be a great help!
this is how i solved it!

```
using UnityEngine;
```

`using System.Collections;`

`public class Mute: MonoBehaviour{`

```
bool isMute;


public void MusicMute (){
    if(isMute == true){
        Debug.Log("Music On");
        AudioListener.volume = 1;
        isMute = false;
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("Music Off");
        isMute = true;
        AudioListener.volume = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Imagining that you are using a GUI Button to toggle...

You can toggle the volume by following:

```
void OnGUI ()
{
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (0, 0, 30, 30), "Music")) {
        if (audio.volume != 0) {            
            audio.volume = 0;
        } else {            
            audio.volume = 1; //or whatever value you want
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can play or stop by following:

```
void OnGUI ()
{
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (0, 0, 30, 30), "Music")) {
        if (audio.isPlaying) {          
            audio.Stop ();
        } else {            
            audio.Play ();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think this is a very good answer as it's suggesting to use the old Unity GUI system, while the original question clearly states using Unity 4.6, where GUI.Button is no longer valid.